# Where is C multiplication result put when calling from GNU AS?

Tags: c, gnu, gnu-assembler

I am calling simple function written in C from Gnu AS program:

C file:

```
long foo(int a, int b){
    return a*b;
}
```

As file:

```
.data 
TEXT: .ascii "Result: %ld\n\0"
.text
.globl main
main:
    pushl $100000
    pushl $100000
    call foo
    addl $8, %esp

    pushl %eax
    pushl $TEXT
    call printf
    addl $8, %esp

    pushl $0
    call exit
```

In result in the %eax register I get: 1410065408 which is obviously wrong.

When multiplying in AS the result is put into EDX:EAX. But how does it work in this case?

When compiling with `-S` option in `gcc` what I get is:

```
    .globl  foo
    .type   foo, @function
foo:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    imull   12(%ebp), %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

Does it mean that the upper half of the result from %edx register is lost?

Comment: `%l` is not a valid printf format specifier. Perhaps you meant `%ld`?

Comment: Of course. Typo. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like you're working on 32-bit x86, so `long` is 32-bit. Even if it were 64-bit though you're performing the `*` operator on `int`s, so the result is an `int`, and can be truncated since the behavior is undefined if it overflows.

If you want to see a 64-bit result, use `(long long)a*b`, return a `long long`, and use `%lld` to print it.

Comment: in fact it will be truncated, because the result of operation between 2 `int`s (except shifting) is an `int`

Comment: @phuclv in fact the behaviour is still undefined so it need *not* be truncated - in this particular case it quite likely is but there are no guarantees that the same will happen with shorts; or ints on 64-bit platforms.

Answer (score 0):

the body of `foo()` is multiplying two integers, they passing the result back in a `long int`  This result in a overflow problem during the multiply operation.

Suggest:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long foo(int a, int b){
    return (long)a*b;
}


int main( void )
{
    long result = foo( 100000, 100000 );
    printf( "%ld\n", result );
}
```

which results in the expected:

```
10000000000
```